# Entity Framework with Condition on SaveChanges

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I work on a project with EF and Linq. I Load Accounts that its DayLock property of its Branch is false (DayLock == false). sometimes I load a account with false value of daylock and before savechanges daylock value changed (it set  true by another service). I want to prevent any balance update when daylock is true. how can I do it?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ctx = new DbTestEntities();
        var x = ctx.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == 1001 && a.Branch.DayLock == false);
        x.Balance = 3322222222;

        // After I check this condition (DayLock == false) another process set DayLock = True  
        // I don't want this update (save changes) be commit

        ctx.SaveChanges();

        Console.WriteLine(x.Balance);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

another process:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var branch = ctx.Branches.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == 2);
        branch.DayLock = true;
        ctx.SaveChanges();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

In the sql I can do this by this query:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Account]
   SET [Balance] = 100
 WHERE (SELECT [DayLock] FROM [Branch] Where [Id] = [BranchId]) = 1
```

Comment: This is a rather complicated subject, a good example here http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @DavidG it doesn't solve by row version or concurrency solutions

Comment: You can check the original value when saving.

Comment: @RezaAghaei after I check the original value it may be changed!

Comment: Combine that with concurrency check.

Comment: Also you can simply use a `Stored Procedure` for update.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
using (var dbContextTransaction = entity.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    //your code
    if() // check condition of true or false
    {
        //if still false then
        dbContextTransaction.Commit();
    }
    else
    {
        //if turned to true then
        dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an override for the SaveChanges method, you can then perform what ever logic checking that you like and decide how to proceed. We have used this method in the past for soft deletes. You can find more info in the URL below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716714(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Although this post is a bit old, I'd like to leave a response.

The best way to do this is using `Optimistic Concurrency Control` approach.

Check [Handling Concurrency Conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency) link to see how it works.

Answer (score -1):

Use  `lock` and `EntityEntry`

```
 lock (ctx)
            {
                if ((bool)ctx.Entry(x).Property("DayLock").CurrentValue == false)
                {
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

Comment: In a concurrent system, the lock only affects to your pod... So you still have the same problem.